# Autolayouts Set Portrait and Landscape Views iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode6

I have a view which has 6 Image Views for displaying images according to my logic, This view can be viewed in Landscape and portrait both.

In Portrait mode it shows images like

```
1  2
3  4
5  6
```

and i want to show this in Landscape mode like

```
1  2  3
4  5  6
```

How can i use constraints on these imageViews so that i can get this desired results.[image: This is the screenshot of my view for ease]

Comment: Looks like you need `UICollectionView` instead autolayout.

Comment: No, the reason for not using UICollectionView is that I am loading images from a webservice and the delegates and weservices were conflicting and that is why i had to create this custom View with my custom swipe gestures functions..

Comment: I think that solve delegates conflict will be easier then create you own collection view.

Comment: Are you targeting iOS 8? You can certainly take advantage of Size Classes to achieve your goal. Although I also think a paging collection view with a simple flow layout might better suit your needs.

Comment: not only iOS 8, this will be used by iOS 7 as well, the conflict is that when the scrollView is scrolled, I need to hit my webservice with the current page number, when the response of that service comes, i need my view to display a loader till that and as the response is received and parsed, the images start loading. the problem is the detecting the scroll view was being done after the collectionView's cellForRowAtIndexpath which caused crash because it had nothing to display in those indexes as those images were yet to come from the webservice.. and this is why i had to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are talking about different designs for landscape and portrait modes. Therefore, you should use size classes.

With size class you can create a set of constraints for landscape mode, another set for portrait mode, and another set for both of them.

Example (from the first link i added):[image]

My recommendations for learning SIZE CLASSES issue (and i checked a lot):

http://www.mangrove.com/en/journal/2015-01-21-auto-layout-for-existing-ios-projects/

http://mathewsanders.com/designing-adaptive-layouts-for-iphone-6-plus/#aspect-ratio-constraint

http://www.imore.com/adaptive-ui-ios-8-explained

Good Luck !